# React Native and pod installation failure

Tags: react-native, cocoapods

I'm trying to install the libary ( pusher ) onto IOS that is made with react-native language.

The command I used was

```
pod 'libPusher', git: 'https://github.com/pusher/libPusher.git', branch: 'push-notifications
```

The error that I got was

```
[!] Unknown command: `libPusher,`
Did you mean: list?
Usage:
    $ pod COMMAND
      CocoaPods, the Cocoa library package manager.
...
```

I have no idea why this pod installation doesn't work. Pod version is 1.0.1.
(pod --version)

Please share any idea with me!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you ever figured this out, but the line Pusher gives you isn't for the command line.  Add it to your Podfile:

```
target 'MyApp' do
  pod 'libPusher', git: 'https://github.com/pusher/libPusher.git', branch: 'push-notifications'
end
```

Then run `pod install` to install it

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `-lc++` to your Tests `Other Linker Flags`